# multiplying a number by 12 in MIPS

Tags: mips

Ok so I am trying to make a crude program in MIPS that multiplies any number by 12. And I decided to use shifting for it. Quite new to MIPS so not sure how to do this. I am sure someone here can be so nice and show me.

```
addi $a0, 2

sll $t0,$a0,2

li $v0,2

move $a0,$t0

syscall

li $v0,5

syscall
```

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: (no, posting random unrelated instructions doesn't count)

Comment: 12 is 1100 bin so you need to shift x left by 1, add x, shift result left by 2

Comment: @jakub_d pretty much adding some values etc like i can write code to get the answer  I want but I can't get the code to perform the proper calculations automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to make 12 into power of two multiplies (which are easy to then do using shift):

```
12 = 4 * 3 =  4 * (2 + 1)
```

So, assuming a0 has the original value you would do in assembly the equivalent of:

```
t0 = a0<<1  # the 2 part
t0 = t0 + a0 # that's the 2+1 done
a0 = t0<<2  # that's the  4 * (2 + 1) put back to the original register
```

So is assembler, still assuming a0 has the number in it (and doing in the same order as above):

```
sll $t0, $a0, 1
add $t0, $t0, $a0
sll $a0, $t0, 2
```

Now a0 has the result

Comment: like this? add $t0, $t0,a0
sll $t0,$t0,2

Comment: By implenting your solution i got a0 to be 180 and it should be 24.

Comment: it works for me - what number did you start with in a0 ? and was it actually in a0, when you were about to call the 1st ssl line? AND the answer as I noted in my answer is in t0 NOT a0, if you want it in a0, the last ssl could be sll a0,t0, 2

Comment: I wan't it in t0 and i started with 2 in a0 and i should get 24

Comment: i mean i get 18 not 180 still off by 6 in this case.

Comment: 18 HEX = 24 decimal, which is probally what you are looking at if using the spim simulator - set the display for decimal.